# What's the oldest version of RabbitMQ that works with Celery v2.1.4?

Tags: django, dependencies, rabbitmq, celery

What's the minimum version of RabbitMQ that Celery v2.1.4 can work with?

Comment: It should work with versions all the way down to 1.7.

Comment: .. but CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES requires RabbitMQ 2.1+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with versions all the way down to 1.7.

.. but `CELERY_AMQP_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES` requires RabbitMQ 2.1+